# What code is running when I call getSystemService() from my activity?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to trace AOSP code from the [grepcode site](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/content/Context.java?av=f).

When I call `getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE)`, it gets to the following code:

```
 @Override public Object getSystemService(String name) {
    if (getBaseContext() == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()");
    }
    if (WINDOW_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
        return mWindowManager;
    } else if (SEARCH_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
        ensureSearchManager();
        return mSearchManager;
    }
    return super.getSystemService(name);
}
```

And since `WIFI_P2P_SERVICE` declared as `public static final String WIFI_P2P_SERVICE = "wifip2p";`, if will not fall in one of the conditions and will go to the `super.getSystemService(name);`

```
Activity extends ContextThemeWrapper, the code there is:
 @Override public Object getSystemService(String name) {
        if (LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
            if (mInflater == null) {
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mBase).cloneInContext(this);
            }
            return mInflater;
        }
        return mBase.getSystemService(name);
    }
```

Here also, the required service name will not match, `mBase` is an instance of `Context` so the code in Context is:

```
public abstract Object getSystemService(String name);
```

which means that classes which extends from it must handle that functionality.
**Well, Where my request is being treated?**

Comment: On grepcode.com, between `Object` and `getSystemService(` there is a down arrow, click it and select "Find derived methods".  It will bring you to the interface's implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know the implementation code of Context is under the package android.app with class name ContextImpl

Here is getSystemService from that class -

```
@Override
public Object getSystemService(String name) {
    ServiceFetcher fetcher = SYSTEM_SERVICE_MAP.get(name);
    return fetcher == null ? null : fetcher.getService(this);
}
```

Edit -
The entry point for WIFI_P2P_SERVICE -

```
registerService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE, new ServiceFetcher() {
    public Object createService(ContextImpl ctx) {
          IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService(WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
          IWifiP2pManager service = IWifiP2pManager.Stub.asInterface(b);
          return new WifiP2pManager(service);
        }});
```